# How do I fix geom_errorbar output errors?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to display error bars on one of my plots and have almost gotten it.  I can get the error bars to appear on the plot correctly other than the fact that two of the error bars do not appear.  Here is my code:

```
    adat <- data.frame(1:8)
names(adat)[1] <- "Technology"
adat$Technology <- c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2")
adat$Behaviors <- c("Low Moisture","High Moisture","Low Density","High Density","Low Moisture","High Moisture","Low Density","High Density")
adat$Average.duration <- c(374,347,270,313,273,280,242,285)
adat$sd <- c(207,107,120,920,52,61,50,84)

limits <- aes(ymin = adat$Average.duration - adat$sd, ymax = adat$Average.duration + adat$sd)

ggplot(adat, aes(x = Behaviors, y = Average.duration, fill = Technology)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  ylim(0,500) +
  geom_errorbar(limits, position = position_dodge(.9), width = .75)
```

When I run the above code I get the following output:
[image]

I don't know why two of the error bars do not show up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your error bar is extending beyond the limits you set with `ylim()`. Try plotting using this:

```
limits <- aes(ymin = Average.duration - sd, ymax = Average.duration + sd)

ggplot(adat, aes(x = Behaviors, y = Average.duration, fill = Technology)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  geom_errorbar(limits, position = "dodge")
```

[image: First Plot]

In addition, notice, you do not need to supply `adat$...` to your `limits` call 
since you will "set it" in your call to `ggplot()`.

The takeaways being that `ylim()` and `scale_y_continuous()` will remove data points outside their range. If you want to still plot within the `0 to 500` y-range, you will need to use `coord_cartesian()`:

```
ggplot(adat, aes(x = Behaviors, y = Average.duration, fill = Technology)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  geom_errorbar(limits, position = "dodge") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 500))
```

[image: Plot With Coord_Cartesian]